# Fill in NGINX cache from different service

Tags: nginx, caching

I have an idea to form NGINX cache in non most common way and I want to ask if this is really possible to achieve.

The common way we all are used is when request hits the backend service and only then it's cached in NGINX.

What I want to achieve is to form that NGINX native cache from separate service. That means I want to manipulate hashed keys that are stored in memory via some NGINX module and also create that directory structure with files that contain cached payloads.

The questions would be:

1. Is this possible?
2. How to achieve this, what modules should I include into NGINX, etc.?
3. NGINX is writing cached data to filesystem using some algorithm described here: http://czerasz.com/2015/03/30/nginx-caching-tutorial/. What is actually stored in the first line of that cached file? Everything from the second line is payload but there are some bytes written into the first line that are non readable and cache does not work in case this line is removed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just need this kind of cache ability or you want this feature in nginx? https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster can achieve this.

Comment: I wanted this ability in nginx. Eventually I went with alternative approach: integrated nginx with memcached and now memcached is used as the first caching layer.